# Add (BEM) classes to Wordpress menu list-items and anchors

Tags: php, html, wordpress, bem

I started off my project by building static html templates. My 'main' navigation looks like this:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <a href="#" class="page-head__logo">
        <img src="img/interface/logo.png" alt="Wireforce logo" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="site-nav__toggle">Menu</a>
    <ul class="site-nav__list">
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Security</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">About</a></li>
        <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm aware I can target Wordpress anchors in the css with `.site-nav li a {}` but I'd like to keep with my BEM naming convention for consistency.

Within `functions.php` I can see that using `wp_nav_menu` I can specify classes for the container/ul but not the list-items/anchors. Can anyone recommend the 'best' way of achieving what I'm after? Doing a bit of reading, it seems that a *walker* class could be the way to go? So I'd really appreciate some advice on this topic or if there's a better method.

For reference my `wp_nav_menu` script currently looks like this:

```
function html5blank_nav() {
    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
        'menu'            => '',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="site-nav__list">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right about a walker. Try something like this, and pass `new Custom_Walker` to your `walker` key in the array of args fed to `wp_nav_menu`

```
<?php

// functions.php
// OR - preferrably - some file of it's own that you `include` by other means.

class Custom_Walker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * The $args parameter holds additional values that may be used with the child
     * class methods. Includes the element output also.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @abstract
     *
     * @param string $output            Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $object            The data object.
     * @param int    $depth             Depth of the item.
     * @param array  $args              An array of additional arguments.
     * @param int    $current_object_id ID of the current item.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {    
        $anchorEl = sprintf(
            '<a class="site-nav__link%s" href=\'%s\'>%s</a>',
            ($item->object_id === get_the_ID()) ? ' site-nav__link--active' : '',
            $item->url,
            $item->title
        );

        $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class="site-nav__item">%s\n", $anchorEl);
    }//end start_el()

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * The $args parameter holds additional values that may be used with the child class methods.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @abstract
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $object The data object.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of the item.
     * @param array  $args   An array of additional arguments.
     */
    public function end_el(&$output, $object, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {   
        $output .= '</li>';
    }//end end_el()
}//end class
```